# Аналоги apt на Windows

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, apt

Есть что-то на подобие apt только для Винды? Задолбало постоянно лазить по сайтам и искать нужные программы. Хотелось бы иметь все или большинство стандартных программ (на подобие Браузеров, архиваторов, и т.п.) в одном месте

Comment: WinGet https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/

Comment: Microsoft Store.

Comment: Есть ещё AppGet. Вот тут перевод истории о том, как её "убили", выпустив winget: https://habr.com/ru/company/dcmiran/blog/504414/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например
https://chocolatey.org/

Ну и как сказали в комментариях:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/
- https://habr.com/ru/company/dcmiran/blog/504414/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cygwin.com/

Из [wikipedi-и](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)

> Cygwin (произносится /ˈsɪgwɪn/)[2] — UNIX-подобная среда и интерфейс
> командной строки для Microsoft Windows. Cygwin обеспечивает тесную
> интеграцию приложений, данных и ресурсов Windows с приложениями,
> данными и ресурсами UNIX-подобной среды. Из среды Cygwin можно
> запускать обычные приложения Windows, также можно использовать
> инструменты Cygwin из Windows.

Можно пакетики ставить, есть Икс - есть g++/gcc, и можно даже порты таскать. Не всё конечно без бубна собирётся под винду...
Но элементарные штуки типа nmap, apache2, nginx, ssh, wget, rtorrent, python, curl итд - т.е. попса всякая - по дефолту лежит в пакетах и собирается с сорцов тока так.

Но самый кайф - это конечно X/xterm - в нём screen - в нём bash, в нём vim и возможность заскриптовать винду через cron, без этого PowerShell-а, который не знает даже о регистре...